# Creating a library .jar from Github in Netbeans

Tags: maven, netbeans, jar, java

I am trying to use a library that is available on GitHub ([MailChimp API Wrapper for Java](https://github.com/Ecwid/ecwid-mailchimp)). Unfortunately, they do not distribute the library classpath .jar or javadocs as a direct download.

Attempting to build the classpath .jar myself, I downloaded the .zip file which contained a Netbeans project and opened the Netbeans project (which is a Maven project... I'm not too familiar with Maven). I tried to clean & build the project (hoping for it to spit out a nice .jar which I can import into my other project).

[image]

But, the clean & build failed with this message:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.2:test (default-test) on project ecwid-mailchimp: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.2:test failed: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ? -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

The website it directs you to says:

> This error is reported in case the execution of a plugin failed due to some unforeseen event. For example, uncatched runtime exceptions caused by the plugin will raise this error. You should report this problem to the maintainer of the plugin.

Now, I'd love to believe I've done everything correctly and that this is, indeed, a problem with the build. But, before I go sending a nastygram email to the API creator, I'd like to ensure that the error is not on my end.

So, the question is thus: If you had a Netbeans Maven project that you wanted to compile to create a library classpath .jar to use in another project, what would you do? And am I doing it correctly?

EDIT:

Building the project with -e yielded this as a result:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.2:test (default-test) on project ecwid-mailchimp: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.2:test failed: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ? -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.2:test (default-test) on project ecwid-mailchimp: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.2:test failed: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ?
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.2:test failed: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ?
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ?
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ForkClient.close(ForkClient.java:245)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:282)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:695)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAllProviders(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:666)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:624)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:587)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    ... 20 more

Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Soo.... that's a thing.

Comment: goto terminal (or command line) and invoke `mvn clean install -e` from the directory where `pom.xml` is placed for this project and post the exception stacktrace if you just want jar and don't want to care about their test execution then you can just run `mvn clean package -DskipTests` and that will generate jar that you need

Comment: @JigarJoshi, where is the `mvn` executable located by default? Not in the JDK `/bin`.

Comment: it is not part of jdk, you will have to [download the archive and extract it and then set it to path](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)

Comment: Adding `-DskipTests` to the Maven Global Execution Options worked. Thanks! If you want to leave an answer...

Comment: Sure, added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want jar and don't want to care about test execution (where it dies) you can invoke

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

to skip surefire plugin's execution and to get the jar

and then in your project add this artifact as dependency (assuming it is maven project)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId></groupId>
    <artifactId></artifactId>
    <version></version>
</dependency>
```

if you want to see what is going wrong, I doubt it is the jvm crashed most likely related to OutOfMemory, I would increase maven's memory by setting higher heap space in `MAVEN_OPTS` and increasing surefire's plugin jvm's heap if it is a fork

Comment: Meh. I imported the .jar into my project and when I compiled and run, I got this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/JsonParseException`. That shows me the dependencies did not come with the .jar?

Comment: no, its dependency won't come that way, to fix see update in answer

Comment: if your project isn't maven based and you can't make it then the hacky workaround would be add all the jar that your this new project needs as well

Comment: I did it. The good news is the Maven project downloaded them all for me I just had to go copy/paste them 1-by-1 into a folder and import the .jars. Works great.